# Matrix multiplying arrays with Numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix

I have a 5x5 array of arrays and I'm trying to matrix multiply the transpose of one row with another row.

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([1, 4, 6, 4, 1])
b = np.array([-1, -2, 0, 2, 1])
c = np.array([-1, 2, 0, -2, 1])
d = np.array([-1, 0, 2, 0, -1])
e = np.array([1, -4, 6, -4, 1]) 
f = np.vstack([a, b, c, d, e])

result = np.dot(f[1, :].T, f[1, :])
```

I assumed this would work but apparently

```
f[1, :].T
```

ends up becoming

```
[-1, -2, 0, 2, 1]
```

rather than

```
[[-1]
 [-2]
 [ 0]
 [ 2]
 [ 1]]
```

and so `np.dot` treats it like a real dot product rather than doing matrix multiplication.

I found out that list slicing where one index is an integer and all others are `:`s reduces the dimension by one so so the shape of `f[1, :]` is not `(1, 5)` but `(5,)` and so transposing it does nothing.

I've been able to get it to working using `f[1, :].reshape((1, 5))` but is there a better way of doing this? Am I missing a simple way of getting the transpose without having to reshape it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `np.newaxis` to add a dimension when slicing, to compensate for the dimension that is otherwise lost.

```
f[1, :, np.newaxis]
```

produces the single-column 2D array you want. Putting `np.newaxis` before the colon would give a single-row 2D array.

Answer (score 1):

For numpy arrays it is often favorable to have this behavior, to circumvent this you can always use the numpy matrix class.

```
>>> f = np.matrix(f)
>>> f
matrix([[ 1,  4,  6,  4,  1],
        [-1, -2,  0,  2,  1],
        [-1,  2,  0, -2,  1],
        [-1,  0,  2,  0, -1],
        [ 1, -4,  6, -4,  1]])

>>> f[1,:].T
matrix([[-1],
        [-2],
        [ 0],
        [ 2],
        [ 1]])

>>> np.dot(f[1, :].T, f[1, :])
matrix([[ 1,  2,  0, -2, -1],
        [ 2,  4,  0, -4, -2],
        [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
        [-2, -4,  0,  4,  2],
        [-1, -2,  0,  2,  1]])
```

As this is the matrix class `*` will denote matrix multiplication, therefore you can simply use:

```
f[1,:].T * f[1,:]
```

Also you may want to consider `np.outer` for this kind of operation:

```
>>> np.outer(f[1,:],f[1,:])
array([[ 1,  2,  0, -2, -1],
       [ 2,  4,  0, -4, -2],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [-2, -4,  0,  4,  2],
       [-1, -2,  0,  2,  1]])
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the individual slices to retain their "matrixness" then you should cast f to a numpy.matrix, which preserves the matrixness.

```
 fm = numpy.matrix(f)
```

then

```
numpy.dot(fm[1,:].T,fm[1,:])
```

will return an nxn matrix

Comment: This is exactly what I posted, why redo this?

Comment: Simple, we submitted our answers nearly simultaneously.

Answer (score 0):

Following the accepted answer, I prefer to use  `None` instead of `np.newaxis`, which is a little verbose for my tastes. For example,

```
f[:,None]
```

does the same thing as `f[:,np.newaxis]`.

Answer (score 0):

I am late to the party here, it is worth noting that the NumPy [webpage](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.matrix.html) I accessed today warns that

```py
class numpy.matrix(data, dtype=None, copy=True)
```

might be removed.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31708806)